# Can't find module on migrating ember-cli app to TypeScript

Tags: ember.js, typescript, ember-cli

I want to try ts inside my ember project ( I try it before on small applications )

So i have

```
"ember-cli-typify": "^0.3.1",
"typescript": "^2.0.3"
"typings": "^1.4.0"
"ember-cli": "2.4.3"
```

Inside my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "ember": ["node_modules/at-types-ember"],
      "npm:*": ["local-types/*"],
      "*": ["local-types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "app/**/*"
  ],
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I try to move `app/app.js` into `app/app.ts`

inside file I have next

```
import Ember from 'ember'; // this was solved via typings dt~ember
import Resolver from './resolver.js'; // here I just add `.js` but I'm interested how to avoid it
import loadInitializers from 'ember-load-initializers'; // here I have first error
import config from './config/environment';
```

inside `typings/index.d.ts` I add line

```
 declare module 'ember-load-initializers' { var out: any; export = out; }
```

But I still got

```
 .../tree_stabilizer-output_path-UJl8FIXV.tmp/apollo/app.ts (6, 30): Cannot find module 'ember-load-initializers'.
```

I try put declaration into separate file and add it into `files` section, but got the same result

P.S. I try to use `tildeio/broccoli-typescript-compiler` but It doesn't work for me ( or I do something wrong ) - but if you have some instruction for it ( in couple with ember-cli ) -- it will be great if you share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can try this:

```
yarn add typescript -D
ember install ember-cli-typescript@latest
```

https://github.com/typed-ember/ember-cli-typescript#setup-and-configuration

---

installing typescript before hand will prevent this error:

> Cannot find module 'typescript'