# Fixing Ember Load Initializers when converting to typescript

Tags: typescript, ember.js

Utilizing the ember quick start tutorial trying to convert from `Javascript` to `Typescript`. Changing the `.js` files to `.ts` files throw an error for the `ember-load-initializers` import. The application will not run without this error is resolved.

I've tried the suggestions list in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906524/cant-find-module-on-migrating-ember-cli-app-to-typescript), but was unsuccessful.

Comment: have you tried using `https://github.com/typed-ember/ember-cli-typescript` addon?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you converted the `app/app.js` file and there isn’t yet typing (or you don’t have types installed) for the `ember-load-initialzers` addon. You should be safe leaving that file as a JS file which should fix your problem for now